# How can I determine if I can use a photo commercially?

Tags: legal, copyright

I was searching for a picture for my project, an iPhone app which I'm planning to sell upon its completion. I found it on a [defunct website that is now hosting spam]. This website offers "free" images for the users of myspace and allows them to customize their pages. On this website I also found a contact link which brought me to... nothing.

The image fits perfectly with my project and I didn't find anything else. Can I use that Image commercially? I'd like to contact those guys and even buy the rights to the image.

Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 7):

I would say you almost certainly cannot use that image commercially, without getting permission.  If that site is legitimate, it would appear their intention is providing layouts and images for personal use.

Only thing I can think of is to go to [tineye.com](http://www.tineye.com/) and enter that drum image there, and see if you get any hits.  You might be able to discover the original copyright owner.

Edit: I went and had a look at the site.  The images there have been uploaded by website users.  There is a small notice:

> We are not affiliated or associated with Myspace.com in any way. We do
>   not claim ownership over images hosted on this site

So no, they do not own that image and have no authority to allow you to use it commercially (or otherwise).  Your best bet is to try tineye or search stock sites for a legitimate image.

Comment: 0 Clicks, It couldnt find anything.

Comment: Since that is a site dedicated to myspace layouts and images, maybe someone uploaded a personal image.  Try a Google image search on: drum site:myspace.com and go through the results.  If you find it, it will take you to their myspace page and with any luck you can contact them.